# JSONB Joining with the Contains Operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have two tables, `ClaimPaymentHistory` and `RemittanceHistory` which I am currently joining with the following query.

```
select rh."EventHistory"
from "ClaimPaymentHistory" ph, jsonb_array_elements(ph."EventHistory") payments
inner join "RemittanceHistory" rh
    on payments->> 'rk' = rh."RemittanceRefKey"::text
where ph."ClaimRefKey" = @ClaimRefKey
```

I wanted to improve this query using the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX claim_payment_history_gin_idx ON "ClaimPaymentHistory"
USING gin ("EventHistory" jsonb_path_ops)
```

But I don't appear to get any improvement with this. However, I can see this index being leveraged if I query the EventHistory column of that table using the `@>` operator, for example like so:

```
select * from "ClaimPaymentHistory" where "EventHistory" @> '[{"rk": 637453920516771103}]';
```

So my question is, am I able to create a join using that contains operator? I've been playing with the syntax but can't get anything to work.

If I am unable to create a join with that operator, what would be my best options for indexing?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Ah I had no idea. This project has been my first time working with postgres and yes the syntax around the identifiers was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up refactoring the table structure. Instead of a join through `RemittanceRefKey` I added a JSONB column to `RemittanceHistory` called `ClaimRefKeys`. This is simply an array of integer values and now I can lookup the desired rows with:

```
select "EventHistory" from "RemittanceHistory" where "ClaimRefKeys" @> @ClaimRefKey;
```

This combined with the following index gives pretty fantastic performance.

```
CREATE INDEX remittance_history_claimrefkeys_gin_idx ON "RemittanceHistory" USING gin ("ClaimRefKeys" jsonb_path_ops);
```

Answer (score 1):

That index could be used if you wrote the query like this:

```
select rh."EventHistory"
from "RemittanceHistory" rh join "ClaimPaymentHistory" ph
    on ph."EventHistory" @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('rk',rh."RemittanceRefKey"))
where ph."ClaimRefKey" = 5;
```

However, this unlikely to have good performance unless "RemittanceHistory" has few rows in it.

> ...what would be my best options for indexing?

The obvious choice, if you don't have them already, would be regular (btree) indexes on rh."RemittanceRefKey" and ph."ClaimRefKey".

Also, look at (and show us) the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the original query you want to make faster.